# function default value input

Tags: javascript, ipad, safari

i'm testing my website and everything is worked as wished, but when i work on ipad using safari i got this error:

> Unexpected token '='. Expected a ')' or a ',' after a parameter declaration

This the line of my code where give me the error:

```
function searchLente(side = null) {
```

The problem is that when i test my website on a desktop is working (chrome, safari...) But not on ipad...

PD: My ipad is updated at last version.

Comment: maybe your browser does not support default values.

Comment: Check whether your version of Browser has support of latest ECMAScript format

Comment: @NinaScholz but if its working on safari desktop and not on safari ipad... is this normal?

Comment: You can use this link for reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @KaSkuLL, it could be.

Answer (score 0):

Default values are a ES6 thingy, and most browsers don't support them.

Change it to

```
function searchLente(side) {
    side = side === (void 0) ? null : side;
```

`void 0` is a way to tell `undefined`. This code will check if `size` is `undefined` and then set `size` to a default value (`null`) if is true.

NOTE: This is what typescript actually does when transpiling to ES5 (which don't has defaults).

NOTE2: Don't think that your users will have ES6 enabled, as there are still browsers which don't support it. Use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) if you want to write ES6 code and make it work for most browsers, or simply don't write ES6 code.